# Heroku app is getting crashed

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I recently learned node.js and wanted to deploy my project, which I did on Heroku. However, Heroku is giving me the error messages copied below. Though I have logged the error, I am still not able to figure out the solution.

Here are the logs:

```
2016-04-13T14:24:17.248681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-04-13T14:24:17.256460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-04-13T14:24:30.863162+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rather-website.herokuapp.com request_id=770f4364-
859f-453a-a09c-7f23ddaf6eca fwd="103.248.93.93" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-04-13T14:24:31.537783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rather-website.herokuapp.com request_id=16af5073-
7bb2-431e-bc08-b2fb6773eab8 fwd="103.248.93.93" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-04-13T14:27:59.122567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rather-website.herokuapp.com request_id=c6ba2f2f-
7379-41bf-afc9-550c309e7200 fwd="103.248.93.93" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-04-13T14:29:17.354776+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rather-website.herokuapp.com request_id=088965d7-
ddcf-46ba-a44c-ed1486938993 fwd="103.248.93.93" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-04-13T14:29:21.657898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rather-website.herokuapp.com request_id=94d1eceb-
fa46-4795-82f6-4c369eb04fb6 fwd="103.248.93.93" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-04-13T14:29:24.198371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rather-website.herokuapp.com request_id=6ff6b6be-
e29c-4a5b-b48b-cbf4f4850ccf fwd="103.248.93.93" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
2016-04-13T14:29:28.987226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=rather-website.herokuapp.com request_id=1a1709f0-
9967-4ff0-a9d3-473e147c23e1 fwd="103.248.93.93" dyno= connect= service= status=5
03 bytes=
```

Here is the error:

```js
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `ruby-on-rails` is tagged? Is this a Rails project? If so, add the gem `rails_12factor` and deploy that. It'll give you better insight to errors.

Answer (score 1):

The node.js server is crashing upon HTTP GET request on route `/`. This isn't a platform error, but a code error (likely your index.js file). You will want to check the code for error between the lines:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 //likely some syntax error here
}
```

I highly recommend running the app on your local machine using command such as: `node index.js` to see what part of your HTTP GET code is causing the error. The CLI will give a specific line number on where the error is being caused.

[Heroku Local](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local) is also a great tool for testing your app before deploying it to heroku.